# A positive harmonic function on the punctured plane is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Let $f(z)$ be a positive harmonic function on $\mathbb{C}\backslash
>  \{0\}$. Prove that $f(z)$ is constant.

I have no idea to prove this statement.

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be positive?

Comment: @GitGud It means $f(z)>0$ for all $z\in\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$...

Comment: @Potato Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Liouville's Theorem for harmonic functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a constant so it is bounded away from zero. It is still harmonic. But now the reciprocal is bounded. ... and sub-harmonic.

Comment: Maximum modulus principle. or more basic, mean value property when the radius tends to infinity. Just the same proof of Liouville.

Comment: Well, sometimes I feel that since I already know it, and I already had the training to be able to prove it, I should let the OP build the skills as well. Answers that are themselves an important method I would do completely. But here what is important to remember for other similar problems is already written. The adding of the constant, and the looking at the reciprocal.

Comment: You seem to imply that if $u$ is harmonic and non-vanishing on some domain, then $1/u$ is harmonic there. This is false.

Comment: @MalikYounsi You can do this problem by writing the harmonic function as a logarithm plus the real part of an analytic function, right?

Comment: Liouville assumes entire!

Comment: You just need subharmonic to get the maximum modulus principle, and I am not using Liouville theorem directly, just the style of the proof using the mean value theorem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the reciprocal is subharmonic. Could you please supply some justification?

Comment: ...    me neither.

Comment: @Potato See my answer as a complement to RBG's answer.

Comment: @MalikYounsi Thanks. I knew how to prove that fact at one point in my life...

Answer (score 3):

In RGB's answer, a justification is asked as to why the reciprocal of a harmonic function is subharmonic. This follows from the following :

**Proposition**

Let $u$ be a real harmonic function on some open set $\Omega$, and let $\phi$ be convex on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\phi \circ u$ is subharmonic on $\Omega$.

**proof**:
If $\overline{\mathbb{D}(a,r)} \subset \Omega$, then 
$$\phi(u(a)) = \phi \left( \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} u(a+re^{i\theta})d\theta \right) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(u(a+re^{i\theta}))$$
by harmonicity of $u$ and Jensen's inequality.

Comment: It probably can also be texted directly computing the Laplacian and checking it is $\geq0$. We get $\Delta \frac{1}{f}=\frac{f_x^2+f_y^2}{f^2}$. (Notice we are using here that $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$).

Answer (score 2):

Just consider $u(e^z)$, which is harmonic on $C$.

Comment: but is it positive?